# Undefined variable 'urlpatterns' en django

Tags: django, django-urls

Holaa!! Estoy creando un proyecto siguiendo la guia en la documentación de django y no entiendo porque al iniciar el servidor la consola muestra: *NameError: name 'urlpatterns' is not defined* y VScode no marca ningún error.

urls.py (mysite2):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
]
```

urls.py(app1):

```
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views

urlpatterns[
    path('vista', views.vista1, name='vista1'),
]
```

setting.py (fragmento):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app1',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

En la documentación solo menciona que hay que agregar la *app1* en lista de *INSTALLED_APPS*, no menciona que se tenga que agregar algo mas.

Answer (score 0):

El error se encuentra en urls.py de app1, no estas definiendo urlpatterns, te falto un =, así iría:

```
from django.urls import path
from app1 import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('vista', views.vista1, name='vista1'),
]
```